# Creating a Christmas tree using only while loops

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm running through an online Java course and I'm being tasked with creating a Christmas tree that can be formed based on user input that determines the height of the tree. I cannot print anything within the method that prints the Christmas tree. I can only call other methods which will do the printing for me. The input is simply the height of the tree itself, not the base. The base is the same size regardless of the height.

I've tried a multitude of different options to get the desired result, but the following code is the closest I've come. The result is a crooked version of the tree, but it's close... I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
public static void printStars(int amount) {
    int i = 0;

    while (i < amount) {
        System.out.print("*");
        i++;
    }

    System.out.println("");
}

public static void printWhitespaces(int amount) {
    int i = 0;

    while (i < amount) {
        System.out.print(" ");
        i++;
    }
}

public static void xmasTree(int height) {
    int i = 1; // Stars incrementer

    while (i <= height) {
        int s = (height - i) / 2;
        printWhitespaces(s);
        printStars(i);

        i++;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
    *
    **
   ***
   ****
  *****
  ******
 *******
 ********
*********
**********

Desired result: 

   *
  ***
 *****
*******
  ***
  ***
```

Comment: skip the odd lines and you will not be able to center these with even lines using a fixed width system font.

Comment: IMVHO you do nothing wrong. Unless your desired output differs from what you actually get; in that case specify what you need.

Comment: The second call to `printWhitespaces` seems unnecessary. Oh, and you can get rid of the `i` variables in `printStars` and `printWhitespaces`.

Comment: Sorry, I've added what I need as the desired result. I understand how to make the base, but the structure of the tree itself is what's eluding me.

Comment: Also add what is your input (the height of the whole tree? or the height of the triangle part?) and how is the hieight of the rectangle part related to the triangle part.

Comment: The input is simply the height of the tree itself, not the base. The base is the same size regardless of the height.

Comment: The solutions I see are not dynamic, since static values are passed in the printStars function..check my solution :)\

Answer (score 1):

I didn't run this, but hope it's OK ;)

```
public static void printStars(int amount) {
    while (--amount >= 0)
        System.out.print("*");

    System.out.println("");
}

public static void printWhitespaces(int amount) {
    while (--amount >= 0)
        System.out.print(" ");
}

public static void xmasTree(int height) {
    int i = 1; // Stars incrementer

    // crown
    while (i <= height) {
        printWhitespaces(height - i);
        printStars(2*i-1);

        i++;
    }

    // trunk
    i = 2;
    while (--i>=0) {
        printWhitespaces(height - 2);
        printStars(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! I hadn't thought to multiply i, but I see now that it makes sense in this context.

Comment: Don't you think the param that is passed in printStars should be dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

Something dynamic I wrote, thought to share with you :)

```
    int n=31;
    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        if(i%2!=0){
            for (int j=i;j<=(n+i)/2;j++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int k=1;k<=i;k++){
                  System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=n/4;i++){
        for(int k=1;k<=(n/3);k++){
              System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int k=1;k<=n/3;k++){
              System.out.print("*");
        }
          System.out.println("");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately the restrictions of the assignment meant that I had to use strictly while loops. With that being said, I appreciate this example and I'll definitely refer to it should something come up in the future that might use something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Amount of spaces and stars depend on the height.

```
    public static void xmasTree(int height) {
       int spaces=height-1;
       int stars = 1;
       for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
          printWhitespaces(spaces);
          printStars(stars);
          stars += 2;
          spaces -= 1; 
       }
       spaces=height-2;
       printWhitespaces(spaces);
       printStars(3);
       printWhitespaces(spaces);
       printStars(3);
   }
```

Comment: Don't you think the param that is passed in printStars should be dynamic?